# chrome rich notifications change timeout to close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, settimeout, rich-notifications

I am creating an google-chrome-extension which has rich notifications. I need to change timeout to close in this notification and I need some help with that. This is my code. I have already tried window.close(), but it does not seem to work in Chrome.

```js
var options = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "test",
  message: "body here",
  iconUrl: "icon.png"
};
var msj = chrome.notifications.create(options);
setTimeout(function () {
  chrome.notifications.clear(msj); // how to close?
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome APIs are [mostly asynchronous](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync) (definitely take a look at that link).

[`chrome.notifications.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create) does not immediately create the notification, and will not return the ID. You need to use the callback for that:

```
chrome.notifications.create(options, function(msj) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.notifications.clear(msj);
  }, 1500); 
});
```

Comment: It's worth adding requireInteraction flag into options to override default browser timeout